# Grey unusable area in Boot Camp partition on OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

I have a 500 GB MacBook Pro 2014 with Boot Camp installed (OS X Mavericks and Windows 7) with both OS's booting correctly. I need more space in Windows, so I want to resize the Mac partition to enlarge the Windows partition.

In Disk Utility, there are only two partitions as expected, but the Mac partition only has 38 GB, Windows has 120 GB, and the rest is greyed out. I want to give the extra space to the Windows partition. How can I achieve that?

Output for `$ diskutil list`:

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            53.1 GB    disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data Windows7Ultimate        120.0 GB   disk0s4
```

Output for `$ diskutil cs list`:

```
No CoreStorage logical volume groups found
```